# Error while initiating Firebase Robo test with Google Play services

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

My issue is that I cannot test my Android application using Firebase Robo tests.

The issue started after the integration of [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) for sign in. The error i received then was that the application should update Google Play services.. Testing on my own device works without a problem, and testing on a virtual device works with sign in disabled.

Testing the disabled sign in version on Firebase yields

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.perf.provider.FirebasePerfProvider" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/APP-PATH-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/APP-PATH-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I am not sure whats causing this issue in Firebase

Comment: Could you file a bug report here?  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue, new compiler helped me. To enable `D8` add `android.enableD8=true` to `gradle.properties` file.